# Segmentation fault resulting from attempt to take of value not in memory

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

So I understand my segmentation error is the result of an attempt to access an address not found in the memory. However I'm unsure how to fix the error nice I need to pass the pointer to be able to allocate the memory in the allocate function.

```
int main () {

  int ****s, ****t, ****u, ****v;

  int numRows, numColumns;

  allocateMemory(numRows, numColumns, s, t, u, v);
}

void allocateMemory(int **** &s, int **** &t, int **** &u, int **** &v) {


  s = new int***;
  t = new int***;
  u = new int***;
  v = new int***;

  ****s = ****t; 
  ****t = ****s;
  ****u = ****v; 
  ****v = ****u;

  *s = new int**;
  *t = new int**;
  *u = new int**;
  *v = new int**;

  ***s = ***t;
  ***t = ***s;
  ***u = ***v; 
  ***v = ***u;

  **s = new int*;
  **t = new int*;
  **u = new int*;
  **v = new int*;

  **s = **t; 
  **t = **s;
  **u = **v; 
  **v = **u;

  **s = new int*[numRows]; 
  for(int xCount = 0; xCount < numRows; ++xCount){                                     

    s[xCount] = new int[numColumns];
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is that really [the simplest example you could devise](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: That people run into problems like this is why you should generally write classes to provide a natural interface for things, rather than try to work with bare pointers. I'm having trouble even figuring out what you're *trying* to do here.

Comment: You have waaaaay too many levels of pointers, for a 2D (rows and columns) array.  And a whole lot of lines that do nothing at all.

Comment: ...Not to mention the memory leaks.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a diagram. The diagram starts with s,t,u, and v pointers. Then s and t allocate memory and point to each other, same for u and v. I repeat this  for 3 layers until, I allocate a jagged array, which is pointed to by s,t,u, and v pointers. This is how it has to be done. I guess I want to know is it a simple fix lack of initialization or bigger? I later call a deallocate function.

Comment: `s = new int***; **s` - this is already a problem (let alone the `****` stuff). `s` has been initialized, so `*s` is valid. But `*s` points to uninitialized memory, so `**s` is an error at this point.

Comment: As for whether it is a simple fix, that is impossible to tell because I have no idea what this is even supposed to do (and I really doubt your "*this is how it has to be done*").

Comment: Congratulations, you are a four-star programmer

Comment: Using four stars is immediately a problem.  [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a term of praise, and going for 4 stars — well, let's just say I'm not going to expend any time fixing your code, because where there are 4 stars, there are far too many opportunities for innocent mistakes with experienced programmers, let alone people needing to ask for help.  You need to rethink your code so that you are not using as many levels of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

**First problem:**

```
void allocateMemory(int **** &s, int **** &t, int **** &u, int **** &v) {
  ...

  s[xCount] = new int[numColumns];
```

This won't compile; the types don't match up in this assignment. On the left is `int***`, on the right `int*`. I can guess what you meant, but--

**Second Problem:**

```
void allocateMemory(int **** &s, int **** &t, int **** &u, int **** &v) {
  s = new int***;
  t = new int***;
  u = new int***;
  v = new int***;

  ****s = ****t; 
  ...
```

You just allocated memory *one level deep* from these pointers. Now you're dereferencing them down *four* levels. You're following pointers that don't actually *exist*. This is Undefined Behavior.

**Underlying problem:**

You're trying something far beyond your understanding of pointers and arrays. You must **start with something simpler**. Try an `int` and some pointers to it, then an `int[]` and an `int**`, and so on up. Don't try a new level until the previous one works perfectly; **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Along the way you'll see the value of encapsulation some of these structures in, say, structs.